Creating file link in a table of a newly created file
I am creating a maintenance data workbook. I currently have 1 sheet to enter the maintenance data a user just performed that gets transferred to a "Database" sheet. I then have a sheet for "Archives".
The "Archives" sheet has a button that creates a copy of the "Database" sheet and saves it as a separate workbook in a specified folder with the name of the file corresponding to the Date range covered by the sheet. I am trying to have the same button also create a new row in a table in the "Archives" sheet that lists the day the archive was created, the date range the archive covers, and a link to open the newly created archive document. It is the link to the newly created document that I am having trouble with.
Also as a note, this is my second time using VBA for anything so I probably won't know most lingo for things.
The following is the code I currently have;
Sub CreateArchive()

'This module does multiple things.
'1 created an archived file and saves it in the Inspection Archive folder
'2 adds an entry into the archive table

                'Creating the file

    'file name dims
    Dim startdate As String
    Dim enddate As String
    Dim archivefilename As String
    
    'archive file path dim
    Dim path As String
    
    'archive data source dims
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
    
    'Storing source workbook/sheet values now as it is currently the active workbook and sheet.
    Set sourceWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceWS = sourceWB.Sheets("Database")
    
    startdate = sourceWS.Cells(2, 38)
    enddate = sourceWS.Cells(4, 38)
    
    'Copying data to transfer
    sourceWS.Copy
    

    'Naming archive workbook
    archivefilename = ("Site Inspections From " + startdate + " to " + enddate + ".xlsx")
    
    'Setting path to save the archive
    path = "savefilepath"
    
    'creating a new workbook off the copied data and saving it
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & "\" & archivefilename & ".xlsx"
    
    'Clearing clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    
    'closes the archived workbook automatically
    Workbooks(archivefilename).Close savechanges:=True
    
    
    
                    'Adding entry to archive table
                    
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Dim rowNum As Integer
    rowNum = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Archives").ListObjects("ArchiveTable").ListRows.Count
    Set newRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Archives").ListObjects("ArchiveTable").ListRows.Add(rowNum)
        newRow.Range(1) = Hyperlink("savefilepath" + archivefilename + ".xlsx", "Open File")
        newRow.Range(2) = Date
        newRow.Range(3) = (startdate + " to " + enddate)
       
    
End Sub

When running I receive a "compile error: Sub or function not defined" and it highlights the "Hyperlink"

The code of Function Hyperlink() should be inlcuded in your file.

FYI you've added ".xlsx" twice to the file name you save the file with.
